# JGraphX getCell(id) doesn't find anything

Tags: java, find, cell, jgraphx

I experience some issues with JGraphX and mxGraphModel.
I convert a petri network described by a Hashmap> into a graph model. In order so I built the following loop. However it seems that when iterating over the childs of a node, it can find the existing cells in the model and add a newone with the same label.
The ligne `v2=((mxGraphModel)(graph.getModel())).getCell(childVertex);` is not working:
The method return null even if a vertice with the same ID is present. Resulting multiple vertices with the same label and incorrect graph.

```
            int j=0;
        for(String vertex: dataPetri.keySet())
        {
            Object v1 =((mxGraphModel)(graph.getModel())).getCell(vertex);
            Object v2;
            //Add only if new vertex
            if(v1 == null)
                v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, vertex, 100, 100*j, 40, 40, "whiteSpace=wrap;textOpacity=100");
            else
                System.out.println("//Found existing parent ////");
            //Looking for links from this vertex
            ArrayList<String> childs = dataPetri.get(vertex);
            if(childs != null)
            {
                int i = 0;
                for(String childVertex: childs)
                {
                    v2=((mxGraphModel)(graph.getModel())).getCell(childVertex);
                    if(v2 == null)
                        v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, childVertex, 100*i, 100, 40, 40, "whiteSpace=wrap;textOpacity=100");
                    else
                        System.out.println("/////////Found existing");
                    graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "", v1, v2);
                    ++i;
                }
            }
            ++j;
        }
```

[image: Produced graph]

Comment: define *is not working.*

Comment: Edited to be more clear.
The method return null even if a vertice with the same ID is present. Resulting multiple vertices with the same label and incorrect graph.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It didn't come from `2=((mxGraphModel)(graph.getModel())).getCell(childVertex);` but from `v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, childVertex, 100*i, 100, 40, 40, "whiteSpace=wrap;textOpacity=100");`

By putting null instead of childVertex, JGraph provide a default id which is not the label.